# Where can I find a big list of WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm a security researcher interested in WordPress. I've been testing several plugins that I found on wordpress official site. I'm looking for a big list of wordpress plugins, does anyone know a site with a list or database of WordPress plugins to download? I've only tested the official site.

Answer (score 1):

if youre looking for a way to get the list of all plugins listed in the WordPress.org Plugin Directory.

here is some advice for you: its been a long time that this has been asked - but anyway.. here my little idea that i can come up with..

Not the best answer but I tried to solve my own problem the best way I could.

You can start with something like this:

[https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=query_plugins&request[page]=1&request[per_page]=400](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=query_plugins&request%5Bpage%5D=1&request%5Bper_page%5D=400)

futhermore: I think it's self-explanatory.

Getting a list of plugins
This will not return ALL plugins but it will return the top rated ones:

```
$plugins = plugins_api('query_plugins', array(
    'per_page' => 100,
    'browse' => 'top-rated',
    'fields' =>
        array(
            'short_description' => false,
            'description' => false,
            'sections' => false,
            'tested' => false,
            'requires' => false,
            'rating' => false,
            'ratings' => false,
            'downloaded' => false,
            'downloadlink' => false,
            'last_updated' => false,
            'added' => false,
            'tags' => false,
            'compatibility' => false,
            'homepage' => false,
            'versions' => false,
            'donate_link' => false,
            'reviews' => false,
            'banners' => false,
            'icons' => false,
            'active_installs' => false,
            'group' => false,
            'contributors' => false
        )));
Save the data as JSON
Since the data that we get is huge and it will be bad for performance, we try to get the name and the slug out of the array and then we write it in a JSON file:

$plugins_json = '{' . PHP_EOL;
// Get only the name and the slug
foreach ($plugins as $plugin) {
    foreach ($plugin as $key => $p) {
        if ($p->name != null) {
            // Let's beautify the JSON
            $plugins_json .= '  "'. $p->name . '": {' . PHP_EOL;
            $plugins_json .= '      "slug": "' . $p->slug . '"' . PHP_EOL;
            end($plugin);
            $plugins_json .= ($key !== key($plugin)) ? '    },' . PHP_EOL : '   }' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
$plugins_json .= '}';
file_put_contents('plugins.json', $plugins_json);
```

Now we have a slim JSON file with only the data that we need.

To keep updating the JSON file, we run that script to create a JSON file every 24 hours by setting up a Cron Job.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If you want more plugins details. Just click this https://yendif.com/   Because the website contains both Joomla and Wordpress Plugins for Free and Paid..its look like full package

Comment: You should include the contents of the link in the answer for better understanding